# select a specific value from multi array by the first row

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm pulling 3 colummns from one table and storing them in an array as such to populate a dropdown menu. The ref_code is used to decide which dropdown it will go to ('Module','Customer','Application') while id is the select value and ref_desc is the display text.

```php
foreach ($test as $t) {
    $aa[] = array($t->ref_code => array('id'=>$t->id, 'ref_desc'=>$t->ref_desc));
};
```

I've been trying to retrieve them using $aa['ref_code'] but have not been getting any success. Help please.

[This question is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320681/multidimensional-array-how-to-get-specific-values-from-sub-array), but I am unable to retrieve the values I want.

I found a solution on another forum but I will also give your solutions a try later. Thank you very much!

```
foreach ($aa as $a => $d) {
    foreach ($d as $ref_code => $dd) {
        echo "<p>". $ref_code ."</p>";
        echo "<p>". $dd['ref_desc'] ."</p>";
        echo "<p>". $dd['id'] ."</p>";
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write it like this? The ref_code (if it's unique) is the key of the array.

```
foreach ($test as $t) {
        $aa[$t->ref_code] = array('id'=>$t->id, 'ref_desc'=>$t->ref_desc);
    };
```

Comment: Each dropdown ('Module','Customer','Application')  then could only have one item.

Answer (score 0):

you need a three dimensional array:

dropdown => ids => displaytext

here we go:

```php
// fill in:
$aa = array();
foreach ($test as $t) {

    if ( !isset($aa[$t->ref_code]) )
        $aa[$t->ref_code] = array();

    $aa[$t->ref_code][$t->id] = $t->ref_desc;

};


// have a drop down:
$myDropDown = 'Customer';
foreach ( $aa[$myDropDown]  as $id => $displaytext )
{
      echo "<option value=\"" . $id . "\">" . $displaytext . "</option>";
}
 .... etc.
```